# Multiply 2 filtered numbers and sum

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

I need to sum the multiplication of 2 numbers based on this example

```
<test>
<stop>
    <id>1</id>
    <unit_id>1</unit_id>
    <unit_id>2</unit_id>
</stop>
<stop>
    <id>2</id>
    <unit_id>1</unit_id>
    <unit_id>3</unit_id>
</stop>
<unit>
    <id>1</id>
    <count>2</count>
    <value>1</value>
</unit>
<unit>
    <id>2</id>
    <count>4</count>
    <value>1</value>
</unit>
<unit>
    <id>3</id>
    <count>2</count>
    <value>3</value>
</unit>
```

The result i want to get is the one below

```
<test>
<stop>
    <id>1</id>
    <sum>6</sum>
</stop>
<stop>
    <id>2</id>
    <sum>10</sum>
</stop>
```

Any tips how to get it?

I tried with this example but the sum of the moltiplication doesn't work, it is ok for only the sum or the multiplication but not both

```
<xsl:template match="stop">
<xsl:variable name="ship_unit" select="id"/>
<xsl:value-of select="sum(following-sibling::unit[id=$ship_unit]/count*following-sibling::unit[id=$ship_unit]/value)"/>
```

Comment: Please explain how exactly you arrived at the result of `<sum>10</sum>`. I would have thought the expected result is 2 * 1 + 2 * 3 = 8.

Answer (score 0):

If I am guessing correctly, you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="unit" match="unit" use="id" />

<xsl:template match="/test">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="stop">
            <xsl:variable name="unit1" select="key('unit', unit_id[1])" />
            <xsl:variable name="unit2" select="key('unit', unit_id[2])" />
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="id"/>
                <sum>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$unit1/count * $unit1/value + $unit2/count * $unit2/value" />
                </sum>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, the result of applying this to your input example will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test>
  <stop>
    <id>1</id>
    <sum>6</sum>
  </stop>
  <stop>
    <id>2</id>
    <sum>8</sum>
  </stop>
</test>
```

and not what you posted.